# Python tkinter scrollbar issue after GUI is idle

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having scrollbar issues with tkinter.  I believe the issue to be a widget creation problem.  I have no issues with scrollbars that build as the GUI is generating (as you can see from my code that would normally work in a case such as that).  I believe my issue is that the GUI builds and goes idle.  I have a canvas with a frame embedded, then labels go in that frame.  What happens is the scrollbar scrolls the whole frame, not the labels in the frame.  Minimal reproducible example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.main_frm = tk.Frame(self, bd=3, relief='ridge')
        self.main_frm.grid()
        self.bttn1 = tk.Button(self.main_frm, command=self.button1, text='F1')
        self.bttn1.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.bttn2 = tk.Button(self.main_frm, command=self.button2,  text='F2')
        self.bttn2.grid(column=1, row=2)
        self.frm1 = tk.Frame(self.main_frm, bd=2, relief='ridge')
        self.frm1.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.frm2 = tk.Frame(self.main_frm, bd=2, relief='ridge')
        self.frm2.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.cnv1 = tk.Canvas(self.frm1, height=400, width=400)
        self.cnv1.grid(row=1)
        self.cnv1.bind('<Enter>', self.bind_mouse)
        self.cnv1.bind('<Leave>', self.unbind_mouse)
        self.cfm1 = tk.Frame(self.cnv1)
        id01 = self.cnv1.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=self.cfm1)
        self.cnv1.bind('<Configure>', self.configure_frame)
        sc01 = tk.Scrollbar(self.frm1, orient='vertical', command=self.cnv1.yview)
        sc01.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='ns')
        self.cnv1.config(yscrollcommand=sc01.set)
        self.cnv2 = tk.Canvas(self.frm2, height=400, width=400)
        self.cnv2.grid(row=1)
        self.cnv2.bind('<Enter>', self.bind_mouse)
        self.cnv2.bind('<Leave>', self.unbind_mouse)
        self.cfm2 = tk.Frame(self.cnv2)
        id02 = self.cnv2.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=self.cfm2)
        self.cnv2.bind('<Configure>', self.configure_frame)
        sc02 = tk.Scrollbar(self.frm2, orient='vertical', command=self.cnv2.yview)
        sc02.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='ns')
        self.cnv2.config(yscrollcommand=sc02.set)

    def button1(self):
        for e in range(50):
            lab = tk.Label(self.cfm1, text='TEST', width=50)
            lab.grid(row=e)

    def button2(self):
        for e in range(50):
            lab = tk.Label(self.cfm2, text='TEST', width=50)
            lab.grid(row=e)

    def bind_mouse(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.cnv1:
            self.cnv1.bind_all('<4>', self.do_mouse_wheel)
            self.cnv1.bind_all('<5>', self.do_mouse_wheel)
            self.cnv1.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.do_mouse_wheel)
        elif event.widget == self.cnv2:
            self.cnv2.bind_all('<4>', self.do_mouse_wheel)
            self.cnv2.bind_all('<5>', self.do_mouse_wheel)
            self.cnv2.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.do_mouse_wheel)

    def unbind_mouse(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.cnv1:
            self.cnv1.unbind_all('<4>')
            self.cnv1.unbind_all('<5>')
            self.cnv1.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>')
        elif event.widget == self.cnv2:
            self.cnv2.unbind_all('<4>')
            self.cnv2.unbind_all('<5>')
            self.cnv2.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>')

    def do_mouse_wheel(self, event):
        parent = event.widget.winfo_parent()
        widg = self.nametowidget(parent)
        if widg == self.cfm1:
            if event.num == 4:
                self.cnv1.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')
            elif event.num == 5:
                self.cnv1.yview_scroll(1, 'units')
        elif widg == self.cfm2:
            if event.num == 4:
                self.cnv2.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')
            elif event.num == 5:
                self.cnv2.yview_scroll(1, 'units')

    def configure_frame(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.cnv1:
            self.cnv1.config(scrollregion=self.cnv1.bbox('all'))
        elif event.widget == self.cnv2:
            self.cnv2.config(scrollregion=self.cnv2.bbox('all'))


main_gui = MainGUI()
main_gui.mainloop()
```

I have tried a dozen adjustments, with no success.  I can't recall everything I've tried based on my understanding of tkinter and scrollbars, but hopefully someone can spot the issue and it can be resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: Bind `<Configure>` on the internal frames, not the canvases.

Comment: You can use ```widget.winfo_children()``` to get all the child frames of the canvas widget. Then you can programmatically bind to all the internal frames.

Comment: @acw1668 + 1
I have tried many things (can't recall all of them) including binding to the frame gridded within the canvas.  That does not fix the problem.  The scrollbar only scrolls the frame, not the labels within the frame.

Comment: Can you please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]? There seems to be a large amount of code not necessary for this specific question. It would also be best to use hard-coded data rather than requiring us to have your database.

Comment: A frame does not support scrolling its children actually.  So scrolling the whole frame inside the canvas is the solution.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help.  acw1668: in all my previous scrollbars, code similar to the above gave the desired results.  I think the issue is the GUI goes idle prior to canvases being populated.  That's a hunch.
@BryanOakley I will provide a minimal reproducible example.  Please keep your eye on this post.  I've seen you help many people with tkinter (was hoping you'd respond).  I'll get on the MRE and that'll be that.  Have to do a bit of a rewrite and test and such.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "GUI going idle". The _only_ way to scroll widgets in a canvas is if they are added via `create_window` or are children of a widget added with `create_window`. Likewise, it is impossible for a  frame to scroll but the contents of the frame do not.

Comment: Gotcha, @BryanOakley
You see what happens when you run the code.  The whole frame (including contents) scroll, not the contents of the frame.  Similar code has worked in the past with several other GUI's.  I basically copy and paste my scrollbar code (sorta).

Comment: I figured it out.  It involved a couple lines of code that needed adjusting.  But, @acw1668 was right--binding "<Configure>" to the frame embedded within the canvas did the trick.  Sorry to ignore your suggestion, acw1668.  I looked back at older apps, and that's exactly what I did for those apps.  Solved.  I can post reproducible working code, if wanted.